# jQuery add class to divs that contain element with class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple layout like this...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="234">
        <div class="left special">
            This is left content
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            This is right content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="944">
        <div class="left">
            This is left content
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            This is right content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="332">
        <div class="left">
            This is left content
        </div>
        <div class="right special">
            This is right content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to use jQuery to target only the row ids that contain the `special` class within them. I have this so far

```
jQuery( ".row:has(.special)" ).addClass( "test" );
```

But it is not adding the `test` class, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use the `.has` method here, to add a class to all elements that have an element with the class `special` in them:

```js
$(".row").has(".special").addClass("test");
```

```css
.test{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="234">
        <div class="left  special"> 
            This is left content special
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            This is right content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="944">
        <div class="left">
            This is left content
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            This is right content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="332">
        <div class="left">
            This is left content
        </div>
        <div class="right special">
            This is right content special
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that this will add the class to the div with the class `row`, hence the multiple colored lines here

Answer (score 2):

You could always go backwards.

```
$('.special').closest('.row').addClass('test');
```

Find the elements with the special class, find their closest parent record with the row class, and put the class on them.  Since you are navigating from child to parent, you know that row has a child of special.

Comment: Thank you, great alternative